# mongoDB graphql mutation with mixed type

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I have a schema already defined and being used and its hard to change the types, in this schema i have the array that holds some data which are of type mixed

```
 "scheduled_dates": {
  "bsonType": "array",
  "items": {
    "bsonType": "object",
    "properties": {
      "date_end": {
        "bsonType": "mixed"
      },
      "date_start": {
        "bsonType": "mixed"
      },
      "working": {
        "bsonType": "bool"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

in graphql, i can get the data by using a custom resolver to get the values of these mixed types [image]

Now what im trying to do is to create a mutation and insert a new document but i get this error, how can i go about this ?
[image]